# Mapbox adds only the last marker?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I'm working with mapbox and placing several markers on the map. My code
looks like this:

```
add.locations.forEach((location) => {
    console.log(location.long + " " + location.lat);
    // add marker to map
    let marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
        .setLngLat([location.long, location.lat])
        .setPopup(popup)
        .addTo(this.map);

    this.markers.push(marker);
});
```

When I look into the console the `console.log(location.long + " " + location.lat);` with 2 different long and lat is visible. But on the map only the last location/pointer is there!?

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the same `el` container for all your markers, so after each loop the new marker will overwrite the previous one (and thus only the last one remains).

You should create a container for each one of your markers:

```
add.locations.forEach((location) => {

  // create a HTML element for each feature
  const el = document.createElement('div');

  // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
  const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat([location.long, location.lat])
    .setPopup(popup)
    .addTo(this.map);

  this.markers.push(marker);
});
```

https://www.mapbox.com/help/custom-markers-gl-js/#add-markers-to-the-map